# jquery append remove and append

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to display 4 objects at a time, but somehow it displayed all the objects. In the following code, I expected 4 users were displayed, then faded out, and the next four users would be displayed. Instead, it displayed all users, then faded out. What was wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.getJSON("MyjSON.json", function(data) {
    var text = '';
    var len = data.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      userName = data[i];
      text += '<p>' + i + '===========' + userName.user.name + '----> </p>'
      if ((i % 4) === 0) {
        console.log(i);
        $('#tFeed').append(text);
        $('#tFeed').fadeOut(3000).remove();
        // I tried $('#tFeed').fadeOut(3000); and it still did not work
        text = '';
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: `var len =` **date** `.length;` or is it suppose to be **data**?

Comment: What is this `date.length` you're using?

Comment: Yes it is supposed to be data.length (corrected on the post, thx). I also tried to use only $(#tFeed').fadeOut(3000); it still just gave me all the users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Animations and fading are asynchronous, but the rest of the loop runs synchronously and doesn't wait for it to complete.

You need to use the callback function of `fadeOut()` to defer actions until it completes.

You need to show the DIV again after it has faded out. And you should use `.html()` rather than `.append()` so the previous users are removed.

```js
const data = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i"];

function displayNext(arr, start, count) {
  let len = Math.min(arr.length, start + count);
  let text = '';
  for (var i = start; i < len; i++) {
    const userName = arr[i];
    text += '<p>' + i + '===========' + userName + '----> </p>'
  }
  $('#tFeed').html(text).show();
  if (len == arr.length) {
    // last group
    $("#tFeed").fadeOut(3000);
  } else {
    $("#tFeed").fadeOut(3000, function() {
      displayNext(arr, start + count, count);
    });
  }
}

displayNext(data, 0, 4);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tFeed"></div>
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.